# Compiling several source (main and headers) files and linking them in ROOT CINT?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, executable, root-framework, .so

Let me first set the context, it is **CERN's ROOT** and **CINT** and **ACLiC** etc.

Suppose I have a main `macro` named `macro.cpp` and two headers `h1.cpp` (contains the definition of a function) and `h1.h` containing the declaration of the function defined in `h1.cpp` similarly I have `h2.cpp` and `h2.h`. The main program `macro.cpp` calls those functions inside `h1` and `h2`. I was successful compiling the source files using:

```
   root [0] .L h1.cpp+
   root [1] .L h2.cpp+
   root [2] .L macro.cpp+
```

which generated three `.so` files `macro_cpp.so`, `h1_cpp.so` and `h2_cpp.so`. I want to know what to do with them ? How do I `link` them so that I have something like a "`macro.out`" or something like that (a single `executable` file of some kind) which I can execute (although I don't know how !) and achieve whatever I wished to achieve with the macro.

**Note:** If I just load all the files using `.L file_name.cpp` etc and just execute the main macro using `.x macro.cpp` then everything works fine and I have results, but this is not what I want ! I want to compile like we do in usual `g++` and by the way in every forum everyone keeps advising on compiling using `.L file_name.cpp+` or `++` .. I would really like to know the whole story. Because nobody seems to explain beyond `.L file_name.cpp+` .. what next ? What to do with the `.so` etc.

I am a beginner, I will really appreciate a simple and step by step answer and explanation.

Thanks.

**Edit-1:** I am working with:

**g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609**

**Edit-2:** ROOT related information:
ROOT **5.34/36** (v5-34-36@v5-34-36, dic 07 2016, 23:31:51 on linuxx8664gcc)
CINT/ROOT C/C++ Interpreter version **5.18.00**, July 2, 2010

Comment: .so are dynamic linked library like .dll on Windows. In short it is compiled code who can be use by several program. You can use the shell command : " ldd ./myprogram" to see all .so needed by your program.

Comment: since you ask "what next?": after `.L macro.cpp+` you can execute functions which are defined in that file, like `.L macro.cpp+; macro(3.1415);`. the saved `.so` will be read the next time you do `.L macro.cpp+` (no recompilation of macros which are compiled already). or you can just load previously compiled `.so` files with `gSystem->Load("macro_C.so");`.

Comment: @pseyfert that's wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile and link you can use a standard compiler instead of Cint/Aclic.
For example, assuming you are working on a *nix platform, you can use the example files below:

**h1.h**

```
int add_one(int a);
```

**h1.cpp**

```
#include "h1.h"

int add_one(int a)
{
    return a+1;
}
```

**h2.h**

```
#include <TLorentzVector.h>

TLorentzVector multiply_by_two(const TLorentzVector v);
```

**h2.cpp**

```
#include "h2.h"

TLorentzVector multiply_by_two(const TLorentzVector v)
{
    return 2.0*v;
}
```

**macro.cpp**

```
#include "h1.h"
#include "h2.h"

#include <TLorentzVector.h>

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    TLorentzVector v;
    v.SetPtEtaPhiM(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    cout<<"calling add_one on "<<a<<": "<<add_one(a)<<endl;
    cout<<"calling multiply_by_two on "<<v.Pt()<<": "<<multiply_by_two(v).Pt()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then you can compile with

```
g++ -c -g -Wall `root-config --cflags` h1.cpp
g++ -c -g -Wall `root-config --cflags` h2.cpp
g++ -c -g -Wall `root-config --cflags` macro.cpp
```

and link with

```
g++ `root-config --glibs` h1.o h2.o macro.o
```

The executable will be `a.out`:

```
$ ./a.out 
calling add_one on 0: 1
calling multiply_by_two on 1: 2
```

You can put these `g++` commands in a script or, when you start having several files and directories, you can write your make file (or cmake). For this last step, see for example the tutorial here

http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/~brisbane/Teaching/Makefiles/Tutorial_1_Makefiles_and_ROOT.pdf

**Note 1**: one advantage of using `g++` is that you will get clear error messages when something doesn't compile. The error messages from Cint can
be difficult to understand--although this is very much improved in root 6 with Cling.

**Note 2**: another advantage of using a standard compiler is that you will be able to easily link your main executable against libraries other than root.

Comment: I agree with using g++ rather than cint/aclic. In fact I know how to link usual C++ sources that doesn't involve root libraries, from your answer I now know how to link root libraries. I will try and will be back. The problem though, with the "`main`" is that I cannot feed a ROOT file name and other parameters during the execution itself as `main` doesn't take such arguments I guess. Suppose the `macro` is like `void macro(TString filename, Int_t nbin)` how does this change things ?

Comment: I can of course change the macro to `main` as you did and then `std::cin>>filename` etc. That will work too.. but asking otherwise just for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: the linking command `g++ `root-config --glibs` h1.o h2.o macro.o` produces a lot of error (something to do with TLorentzVector and root's include path maybe), which I cannot accommodate in a single comment so posting in several (following) comments:

Comment: `h2.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
/home/me/root/include/TVersionCheck.h:34: undefined reference to `TVersionCheck::TVersionCheck(int)'
h2.o: In function `operator*(double, TLorentzVector const&)':
/home/me/root/include/TLorentzVector.h:596: undefined reference to `TLorentzVector::TLorentzVector(double, double, double, double)'
macro.o: In function `main': /home/me/macro.cpp:13: undefined reference to `TLorentzVector::TLorentzVector()'
/home/me/macro.cpp:16: undefined reference to `TLorentzVector::TLorentzVector(TLorentzVector const&)'`

Comment: `/home/me/macro.cpp:16: undefined reference to `TLorentzVector::~TLorentzVector()'
/home/me/macro.cpp:16: undefined reference to `TLorentzVector::~TLorentzVector()'
/home/me/macro.cpp:13: undefined reference to `TLorentzVector::~TLorentzVector()'
/home/me/macro.cpp:16: undefined reference to `TLorentzVector::~TLorentzVector()'
/home/me/macro.cpp:16: undefined reference to `TLorentzVector::~TLorentzVector()'`

Comment: `macro.o:/home/macro.cpp:13: more undefined references to `TLorentzVector::~TLorentzVector()' follow
macro.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
/home/me/root/include/TVersionCheck.h:34: undefined reference to `TVersionCheck::TVersionCheck(int)'
macro.o: In function `TLorentzVector::Perp() const':
/home/me/root/include/TLorentzVector.h:421: undefined reference to `TVector3::Perp() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: with `root-config --libs` you don't get *all* root libraries (or their link commands) but only the basic ones (those one always needs). (and similar for `--glibs`, look at `root-config --help` for the difference).

Comment: In your case you need to add `-lPhysics` after the root-config call: `$(root-config --libs) -lPhysics`. How I found out: `grep TLorentzVector $(root-config --libdir)/*.rootmap` (the *.rootmap files essentially list which class is in which standard root library. the libraries and the rootmap files are in the directory `root-config --libdir`. the rootmap files are plaintext.

Comment: @pseyfert g++ neither  ``root-config --glibs` -lPhysics h1.o h2.o macro.o` nor  ``root-config --glibs -lPhysics` h1.o h2.o macro.o` worked !

Comment: with the same error (missing TLorentzVector things)? does `$(root-config --libdir)/libPhysics.so` exist? when doing `nm -C libPhysics.so` you should see what's inside that library. so you can verify if the TLorentzVector things you need are inside (especially the methods your linker complains about).

Comment: Yes the error is still the same and libPhysics.so library does exist.

Comment: I would suggest you use `argc` and `argv` to pass in your arguments and options (see for example this question on [stackoverflow/3024197](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean).

Comment: Regarding the errors you see when linking: @pseyfert is right, depending on the headers you include, you might need to add some libraries by hand. What version of root are you using? For example, with root `6.04/06` I have
```
$ root-config --glibs                                                                                                       
-L/usr/lib/root -lGui -lCore -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lTree -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic
```
The library is indicated in the top right corner of the doc web page

Comment: edit: "top left corner of the doc". For example, for `TLorentzVector` see [here](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTLorentzVector.html)

Comment: I tried this: ```g++ main.cpp h1.cpp h2.cpp `root-config --libs --cflags` -o main.o``` and I think it worked and produced `main.o` as executable, `./main.o` produces `calling add_one on 0: 1
calling multiply_by_two on 1: 2`

Comment: The single-step `g++ main.cpp ... -o main.o` is also a valid solution. I suggested two separate compilation+linking steps because that seemed to be the request in the initial post.
Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the error you observe, not even when using a root version close to the one you indicate (root `5.34/25`, g++ `4.8.1`). For reference, with this version the libraries indicated in `libPhysics.rootmap` are `-lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore`, which do appear in the list produced by `root-config --glibs`.

Comment: Can you please update the exact command that you are using to link the .o files ? Does just ```g++ `root-config --glibs` h1.o h2.o macro.o``` work without any errors for you ? I am wondering why that single command ```g++ main.cpp h1.cpp h2.cpp `root-config --libs --cflags` -o main.o``` compile without errors while the other one needs library specifications. I am a beginner, it will be great if you share your full linking  command for this exact example and please mention if you include more root headers. Thank you.

Comment: These are the exact commands I used:
`g++ -c -g -Wall \`root-config --cflags\` h1.cpp`
`g++ -c -g -Wall \`root-config --cflags\` h2.cpp`
`g++ -c -g -Wall \`root-config --cflags\` macro.cpp`
`g++ \`root-config --glibs\` h1.o h2.o macro.o`

or alternatively

`g++ macro.cpp h1.cpp h2.cpp \`root-config --libs --cflags\` -o main.o`

Comment: The `root-config` commands expand to
`--cflags` : `-pthread -m64 -I/usr/include/root`
`--glibs` : `-L/usr/lib64/root -lGui -lCore -lCint -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lTree -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic`
Using the same version `5.34/36`. Did you install root from source, or installed it as a ubuntu package? `root-config --features` can tell the what features were enabled when root was built.

Comment: @user2148414 sorry for not coming back sooner. I installed root from the source. I think my installation is complete and no library problems, I am saying this because "g++ macro.cpp h1.cpp h2.cpp `root-config --libs --cflags` -o main.o" this method has solved my problem and since then I have created way more complicated applications involving so many root objects and the compiler didn't complain at all. Your answer and the comments gave me the direction towards this single liner solution and I would like to write an answer aiming to a future newbie, hope nobody minds. Thanks a lot really.

Comment: @user2148414 I would request you to read my update (http://stackoverflow.com/a/41580377/4962474) and comment, if you feel like it, of course. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based mostly on the answer by [user2148414](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479935/4962474), but if one follows the answer will notice that there were some issues with the method of linking the source (*.cpp) files. My answer also addresses another important object called a **TApplication** that will play a crucial role in such applications involving root libraries. The following linking step:

```
g++ `root-config --glibs` h1.o h2.o macro.o
```

will likely show a lot of errors complaining about the root objects like `TWhatever` (in [user2148414](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479935/4962474)'s answer TLorentzVector will show problems). In the comments to that answer one can find the discussion on including various physics libraries that can solve the problem but without discussing that (and I am not comfortable either :) ) let me write down the command that solves everthing.

This procedure is a one-liner, that is no need to compile individual files, create *.cpp files and *.h files as discussed in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479935/4962474) then compile and link and create a single executable named "someExecutable" using:

```
g++ macro.cpp h1.cpp h2.cpp `root-config --libs --cflags` -o someExecutable
```

or better (and one should do it)

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c++14 macro.cpp h1.cpp h2.cpp `root-config --libs --cflags` -o someExecutable
```

This will solve my original answer but for completeness I would like to add a few more things.

**TApplication**

My original motivation was to create an application that talks to "[ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/)" but I didn't want to work with the ROOT shell, [CINT](https://root.cern.ch/cint), ACLiC etc and wanted to work entirely with g++. [user2148414](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479935/4962474)'s and my answer will solve the part of creating an application but the application will not serve any purpose, it will run, create histograms draw them and do all the stuff but all the canvases will close in the end when the code reaches "`return 0;`". To keep the canvases open we will need "`TApplication`". So the consider the `main` of [user2148414](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479935/4962474)'s answer, I am going include just two more lines and include two arguments to the `main`:

**macro.cpp**

```
    #include "h1.h"
    #include "h2.h"

    #include <TLorentzVector.h>

    #include <iostream>
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])  //introduced arguments to main
    {

     // here I introduce TApplication

   TApplication* SomeApp = new TApplication("SomeApp",&argc, argv); 

        int a = 0;
        TLorentzVector v;
        v.SetPtEtaPhiM(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        cout<<"calling add_one on "<<a<<": "<<add_one(a)<<endl;
        cout<<"calling multiply_by_two on "<<v.Pt()<<": "<<multiply_by_two(v).Pt()<<endl;

        //and just before returning 0
         SomeApp->Run();

        return 0;
    }
```